# How can I get a user's mailboxSettings timezone without using an App token?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

### Problem

In our application, we use Office365 SSO to obtain an access token for the user who's logging in. We would like to be able to use this access token to fetch the [mailboxSettings timeZone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get-mailboxsettings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for other users in the logged-in user's directory. [This thread](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/3289#issuecomment-455281471) seems to imply that this can only be done if you authenticate with an App token. Unfortunately that's not an option for us because of security concerns.

### Attempt at solution

I tried to fetch a user's (other than the logged in user) mailboxSettings timeZone using the `/users/{id|userPrincipalName}/mailboxSettings` endpoint authenticating with the logged-in user's access token. I kept receiving 403s.

I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing. Is there any other way to get the configured timeZone for other users in the logged-in user's directory?

Comment: ```/users/{id|userPrincipalName}/mailboxSettings``` definitely requires a User all permission for anyone other than the current user.  I looked into [User.ReadBasic.All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#user-permissions) but that doesn't look like it helps.. Does this [outlook user link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/outlookuser-supportedtimezones?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: You can only read or write another user's Mailbox Setting using Application scopes. Delegated scopes do not support this.